# Verifying a site for Google Apps when your DNS is not managed by your registrar

Tags: google-apps, youtube-data-api

I apologize to come before you with such a rudimentary question, but Google apps is giving me a hard time simply verifying the domain from which I want to make server side YouTube search API calls.

Google is insisting on using the DNS text verification method (even though it provides a link to alternate methods that are not recognized by Google apps).  But my registrar (GoDaddy) is not my authoritative DNS provider.  That honor goes to DynDNS.  So, I'm not sure I can even use Google's automated tool to set up the TXT record.  In fact, it makes me nervous that they want me to grant their app to make changes to the DNS at GoDaddy.

I'm assuming this is a requirement to make server side api calls and retrieve results.  Can someone point me in the right direction? Either how to fulfill the TXT record requirement under this scenario, or how to force Google Apps to accept an alternate verification method?

Thanks

Paul G

Answer (score 0):

If Godaddy isn't managing your DNS, you won't be able to follow the automated flow in the Admin console. You're going to need to manually create the record with DynDNS to accomplish this.

Your host doesn't have specific steps on Google Support site ([here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895)) so you'll need to follow the generic one. Support for your host should be able to help but you can also contact Google Support via the Support section in your Admin console.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I did try the manual approach but Google could not find it even days after adding it.  I then switched to an alternate domain that had a record added and the verification also failed even though Google coughed up the TXT record in the fail response!  Talk about confusing and frustrating!   Thanks